# Android- Image Rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

Is there a way the this problem can be fixed? I tried `invalidate()` but, it still displays the same problem. What happens is that, after opening the page/ the Activity, the images behaves like the one in Figure A. It only renders to my desired layout (Figure B) after scrolling it back and forth. [image]

What I'm trying to do is set the width and heigth of the image during runtime. So this is also in relation to my previous questions : [Images in my HorizontalListView changes it size randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787206/android-images-in-my-horizontallistview-changes-it-size-randomly) and [ImageView dynamic width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781680/android-imageview-dynamic-width-and-height) which received a very little help.

Any tips regarding this matter, please?

EDIT: btw,  my classes are: 
**MyCustomAdapter** (extends baseadapter, this calls the displayimage() from ImageLoader ),
 **MyActivity** and 
**ImageLoader** (this is where my image url are loaded, decoded, displayed asynchronously)

Im also confused as to where i will set the height and width of the imageView. For now, i set it at ImageLoader. It was okay. but i dont know if i did the right thing.

Comment: i set my `android:layout_width="to a fix value"` then my `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the width and height manually at runtime, grab a reference to the ImageView's LayoutParams AFTER the View has been measured by the layout system.  If you do this too early in the rendering phase, your view's width and height as well as its parent view and so on will be 0.

I have some code in an open source library that might help you.  The process is two parts:

1. Set up an OnPreDrawListener attached to the ViewTreeObserver for your control.  My example does this inside of a custom control, but you can do this in your activity as well.
2. Inside the onPreDraw method, your image and it's parent will now have their width and height values assigned to them.  You can make your calculations and then set your width and/or height manually to the LayoutParams object of your view (don't forget to set it back).

Check out this example where I'm applying an aspect ratio to a custom ImageView just before it's rendered to the screen.  I don't know if this exactly fits your use case, but this will demonstrate how to add an OnPreDrawListener to a ViewTreeObserver, removing it when you're done, and applying dynamic sizing to a View at runtime

https://github.com/aguynamedrich/beacon-utils/blob/master/Library/src/us/beacondigital/utils/RemoteImageView.java#L78

Here's a modified version that removes my particular resizing logic.  It also grabs the ViewTreeObserver from the imageView, which is a more likely scenario if you're not implementing a custom control and you only want to do this in the Activity

```
private void initResizeLogic() {
    final ViewTreeObserver obs = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
    obs.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            dynamicResize();
            obs.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

protected void dynamicResize() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = imageView.getLayoutParams();
        // resize logic goes here...
        // imageView.getWidth() and imageView.getHeight() now return 
        // their initial layout values
        lp.height = someCalculatedHeight;
        lp.width = someCalculatedWidth;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```